# Does API 17 support Percent Relative Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I am creating an app and want to use percent relative layout, does API 17 and up support that or am I out of luck? I have not found anything saying no, or anything say yes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you said `percent` means `weight`? As far as I know, the `weight` attribute is available only in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @DysaniazzZ I am not talking about weight, I am talking about Percent relative layouts (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html), thanks for the response.

Comment: Oh, cool! it enlarges my knowledge.

Comment: `PercentRelativeLayout` comes from a support library, so it doesn't matter what API you have.  So yes, API 17 will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kris larson said in the comment. `PercentRelativeLayout` comes from the Percent Support Library, if you want to use it, just import it:

```
com.android.support:percent:24.1.1
```

**It has nothing to do with what API level you are using**.